# Definir quantidade mínima de caracteres em Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como posso definir uma quantidade minima de caracteres que deve ser posta em uma `textbox`?

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2013, criando um site em aspx.

Comment: Você pode verificar a quantidade de caracteres no evento TextChanged do textbox.

Comment: o que exatamente você está utilizando? asp-net MVC? qual versão?

Comment: Você pode tentar usar input: <input id="teste" runat="server" type="text" pattern=".{3,}" title="3 characters minimum" /> 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5

Answer (score 1):

É muito simples, se você estiver usando o `asp:TextBox` basta usar um `asp:RegularExpressionValidator`, ficando da seguinte forma

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valPassword"
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ErrorMessage="Tamanho mínimo pro TextBox é 5"
        ValidationExpression=".{5}.*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Só fazer um filtro verificando a quantidade de caracteres no TextBox.

```
if(textBox1.TextLenght > 5) //Ou qualquer outro número que você definir
{
    FacaOQueTemQueFazer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione uma verificação bem básica no evento onde você vai validar o que está no TextBox.

Vamos considerar `TextBox1` a sua TextBox, e `limite` o limite (obviamente), e considerar esse método um botão, ou sei lá o que você quer fazer com ela.

```
void Validando(Object sender, EventArgs args) {
    if (TextBox1.Length >= limite) {
         // OK, passou do limite mínimo
    } else {
         // não passou
    }
}
```

Ou, usar de uma forma mais simples:

```
if (!TextBox1.Length >= limite) return;
```